# Informally asking a rider/driver to accelerate

Tags: translation, slang

Are any of these constructions legitimate when talking to a person driving a car or riding a motorcycle? If no, which ones can be used?

- "Add (some) gas!"
- "Push the gas!" (This one for the car, meaning "Pushing the gas pedal").
- "Add (some) throttle!"
- "Add (some) revs!" (I'm pretty sure, this one works, but I wanted to be more specific about the action performed by the subject).

Comment: Pedal to the metal!

Answer (score 2):

"Speed up" is the most general phrase I'd use:

> You do know there's a line of a dozen cars behind us?  You should probably **speed up**.

If you're looking for something a little more descriptive, then

> step on the gas
>
> give it some gas
>
> go faster
>
> move it

However, if you want to tell someone to accelerate *as fast as possible*, then these work:

> punch it
>
> put the pedal to the metal
>
> burn rubber
>
> gun it
>
> hit the afterburners

and various others.

(edit) It's much the same for motorcycles, except for "step on" the gas or put the "pedal to the metal", neither of which apply.  Instead you might say something about giving it "full throttle" ... but, when you're riding passenger on a motorcycle, unless you have an intercom system it's hard to communicate.  So I'm not sure you can say anything.

Comment: That helps, thanks. What about the moto?

Comment: @mavzolej   please see my edit

Comment: So, I cannot say "give it SOME throttle"?

Comment: @mavzolej   Well, "give it more throttle".  But you'd only say that if you're teaching someone how to drive, or in some other way helping them to drive better.  Otherwise it sounds too specific, like they don't know how to make the motorcycle go faster.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was asking about.